# C Function call returns back from function. Breakpoint not hitting

Tags: debugging

I tried applying debugger and breakpoint on a piece of code, but the breakpoint didnot hit. Infact on call to that function the program exited successfully. How, i am not able to understand.

Comment: That would mean that the code wasn't run. perhaps the breakpoint is within an if or a function that didn't fire?

Comment: Try moving the breakpoint back to somewhere you "know" the code is reaching, then step through the code to see what the flow is.

Comment: No, the code is running, other breakpoints are hitting. It returns back at the point from where a particular function is called.

Comment: Tom, I did this. Applied a breakpoint at a place within that function.But the control didnot reach there.